# How to copy cell to array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, cell-array

Alright let me explain detailed my question

this below image is displaying my matrix where i want to copy my data

[image]

Alright now what i want to do that is as you can see 1x4 cell
i want to copy it as an array to another variable such as

```
    input_values=ones(1,4);%init
    input_values=input_matrix_training(1);
```

So at the above i am trying to copy the elements in that cell array which is row 1 to the input_values array. But if i do as i above i am getting this instead of the values that array contains. ty

[image]

instead of above it should be like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other values are a cell, and are thus best referenced with `{}` instead of `()`. Also, sometimes they need to be wrapped into `[]`, depending on the format. Plus the fact that you don't need to initialize input_values, and what you should do becomes this:

```
input_values=[input_matrix_training{1}];
```

Or you can just use cell2mat

```
input_values=cell2mat(input_values(1));
```

Comment: ok it is not working as i want. those values have [] and they should not have that

Comment: so it should become double array

Comment: i found the way : input_values=cell2mat(input_values);